# What does "new" in cpp returns, can we assign a value to a object variable using constructor?

Tags: c++, class, oop, binary-search-tree, class-constructors

I am trying to insert data in BST using cpp.
I used the fallowing code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(int data){// Constructor...
        data = data;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;

    }
};
void Pre_Order_Trav(Node* Root){
    if(Root==0) return;
    cout << Root->data << " ";
    Pre_Order_Trav(Root->left);
    Pre_Order_Trav(Root->right);

}
Node* Get_New_Node(int data){
    Node* temp;
    temp = new Node(data); 
    //temp-> data = data; *******************************Watch Here****************
    temp->left =  NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;

}
Node* Insert(Node* Root,int data){
    //cout << "Inserting: " << data<<"\n";
    if(Root == NULL){
        Root =  Get_New_Node(data);
    }
    else if(data <= Root->data){
        Root->left = Insert(Root->left,data);
    }
    else{
        Root->right = Insert(Root->right,data);
    }
    return Root;
}

int main(){
    int n,x;
    //cout << "Enter the size of data: ";
    //cin >> n;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Enter data: ";
    Node* Root = NULL;
   Root= Insert(Root,11);
    while(cin >>x) Insert(Root,x);
    cout << "\n";
    Pre_Order_Trav(Root);
}
```

Node class has a constructor which assigns the given data to data and NULL to left and right.
When the "Watch Here" line is commented I am not able to traverse the tree, but when it is uncommented I was able to traverse successfully. Isn't `temp = new Node(data)` 
is same as `temp->data = data` ?

Comment: Answer 1: `new` returns a pointer.  Answer 2: you should never be using the `new` operator directly in C++.

Comment: All of the code you have shown traverses the tree in a manner that depends on the `data` member.   `temp` is assigned the result of a `new` expression so, by commenting out the line that sets `temp->data`, you are leaving the `temp->data` uninitialised.   Accessing the `data` member of that (pointed to) structure later on - such as when traversing the list - then gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
data = data;
```

in the constructor is assigning the argument `data` to the argument `data`, virtually doing nothing.

It should be

```
this->data = data;
```

to initialize the member variable `data`.